# Slider con espacio en blanco que no logro detectar

Tags: html, css, animación, slider

Estoy armando un slider responsive dentro de la etiqueta `<figure>`
pero al pasar la ultima imagen corre un espacio en blanco como si hubiera una `<img>` vacia...

Les muestro el código:

```css
@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}

body { margin: 0; } 
#slider { overflow: hidden; }
#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; }
#slider figure { 
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 10s slidy infinite; 
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
<figure>
<img src="https://ceromarket.com.uy/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/Huerta.png" alt>
<img src="https://ceromarket.com.uy/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/Mapa-1.png" alt>
<img src="https://ceromarket.com.uy/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/Cuidado.png" alt>
</figure>
</div>
```

Revise el `html` y no encontre el error, supngo que debe ser en la propiedad animation, la variable de `slidy` o algo de eso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se debe a que tu CSS esta pensado para 5 imágenes:

- La animación `slidy` tiene 5 "pausas".
- El `figure` mide 500% y cada `img` ocupa `20%` del `figure`, lo que indica que entran 5 imágenes.

#### Solución:

- La animación `slidy` habría que modificarla para que sea para 3 imágenes.
- El `figure` debería medir `300%`
- Cada `img` debería ocupar `1/3` del ancho del `figure`.

Ejemplo:

```css
@keyframes slidy {
  0% { left: 0%; }
  20% { left: 0%; }
  30% { left: -100%; }
  50% { left: -100%; }
  60% { left: -200%; }
  80% { left: -200%; }
  100% { left: 0; }
}
body { margin: 0; }
#slider { overflow: hidden; }
#slider figure img {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  float: left;
}
#slider figure {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% * 3);
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 10s slidy infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://ceromarket.com.uy/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/Huerta.png" alt>
    <img src="https://ceromarket.com.uy/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/Mapa-1.png" alt>
    <img src="https://ceromarket.com.uy/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/Cuidado.png" alt>
  </figure>
</div>
```